# Symfony2 multiple entity field (not expanded) is empty (when the value is set)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have `ManyToMany` field with type `entity`:

```
$builder
    ->add('types', 'entity', [
        'class' => 'My\Entity\Type',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'Types',
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices' => $choices,
//      'expanded' => true
    ])
```

**The problem**: using `expanded => false` (as it is set by default) I got an empty multiple select (real value is not empty); using `expanded => true` I got set of checkboxes **correctly** set. What can cause this behavior?

Comment: This sound weird ...

Comment: Yes! I also tried passing `'data' => $choices` - the behavior is the same (all checkboxes are set, but no options are selected)

Comment: Why 'choices' ? you can use 'property' option from Type class.

Answer (score 0):

Faced it some days ago and was really frustrated with no answers.

1. No magic here.
2. Check your logs (browser and server).
3. If logs have smth -> fix it, nope -> next step.
4. Dump your current info on the form, if you see, that there's something wrong try to use [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), if you think it's fine -> next step.
5. So the only reason here is that some JavaScript is making tricks with your form. It make take some time to find it, but it's so.

Another developer was rearranging my form with straight json-data and .toString()-function was changing my array, but check-boxes are fine with it.